Improving TimescaleDB Compression Ratios; Using Brotli Parquet to Compare
I've got about 435 million rows of the form:
time, sensor_id, sensor_value
where time is a unix timestamp rounded to one decimal point, sensor_id is an integer, and the sensor_value is a float. The timestamps are one second apart, and for each timestamp, there are around 250 unique sensor_ids.
In Python, I found that I was getting the best compression ratios if I compressed using multiple parquet files, spaced out by one hour at a time. Using this for each file:
df.sort_values(by=['sensor_id', 'time']).reset_index(drop=True).to_parquet('out.parquet', compression='brotli')
the total file size of all the parquet files combined is 120 MB.
I didn't expect to get quite as good of compression ratios in TimescaleDB in PostgreSQL since it doesn't use brotli compression, but I'm still getting compressed sizes that are a fair bit larger than I would like. The best I could get was 964 MB, which is about 8x bigger.
Here's how I set up the table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.sensor_data
(
    "time" timestamp(1) without time zone NOT NULL,
    sensor_id integer NOT NULL,
    sensor_value NUMERIC(20, 3) NOT NULL
);

SELECT create_hypertable('sensor_data', 'time');

-- (insert all data)

ALTER TABLE sensor_data
SET
(
timescaledb.compress,
timescaledb.compress_segmentby='sensor_id', 
timescaledb.compress_orderby='time'
);

SELECT compress_chunk(c) from show_chunks('sensor_data') c;

I've tried the following variations:

Using a double precision type instead of a numeric(20, 3) for sensor value
Using chunk sizes of one hour (similar to what I'm doing in Python) rather than the default 7 days
Using numeric(10, 3) instead of numeric(20, 3)

However, these changes either did nothing or made the compression ratios worse:

Do you have any suggestions for things I can try to improve the compression ratio, or is this as good as it's going to get?

You could try to compress three separate tables instead, each just a vector. A list of times, then a list of sensor id's, then a list of sensor values. That might permit the compressor to take more advantage of the self-similarities in the data. If the timestamps are closely spaced, and especially if they are regularly spaced, then store the differences of successive timestamps. Similarly you could store the difference of successive sensor values, if the changes from timestamp to timestamp tend to be small. That would compress better as well, and both are easy to undo on the other end.

Are you trying to hack/contribute to the timescaledb project itself, or are you thinking you can just make some configuration change?

@jjanes, I'm hoping I can just make some configuration change, or structure my tables and compression settings differently.

Your python code is too concise for me to figure out how to test it myself, or what a df is, or what libraries are in use.  I tried to compress the underlying PostgreSQL data files (not a "df" object) with the command line compressors, and in my hands brotli is insanely slow.  On a large data file it never finished, on a tiny one it didn't seem to compress very well.  Maybe it is faster on parquet files?

@jjanes, df is common syntax for a pandas dataframe in Python. It is true that brotli is much slower than the other common compression methods, so your result doesn't surprise me. If you don't mind sharing, how did you compress the underlying PostegreSQL data files with brotli? I'd love to try it myself.

I just did cat $PGDATA/base/16384/* | time brotli | wc -c to get a rough estimate of compression time and space savings.  Definitely nothing that could be put into production, just a crude test.  On larger sizes, brotli came out about the same compression as xz, but 4 times slower.  (And xz is no slouch when it comes to slowness!).  Another thing I noticed is that timescale compression and brotli reduced the space by about the same amount (5 fold), but brotli after timescale reduced it further yet (another 3 fold), which really surprised me.
